# SyntaxError sending remote ice candidates in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, dom, webrtc

I'm using [SimpleSignalling server](https://github.com/ShareIt-project/SimpleSignaling) to connect two peers. The basic process is:

[PubNub](http://pubnub.com) broadcasts the creation of peer A

```
pubnub.subscribe( {
      channel : 'mimis/peer/awaken',
      message : function( msg ) {
          var dest_uid = msg
          if( server.uid() != dest_uid ) {
              onawaken( dest_uid )
          }
      },
  } )
```

Peer B creates a new PeerConnection

```
function onawaken( uid ) {
    var servers = null
    connections[uid] = new webkitRTCPeerConnection( servers,
                                                    { optional: [{ RtpDataChannels: true }] } )

    function gotCandidate( event ) {
        if( event.candidate ) {
            server.send( event.candidate, uid, server.room() )
        }
    }
    connections[uid].onicecandidate = gotCandidate

    try {
        channels[uid] = connections[uid].createDataChannel( "mimisChannel",
                                                            { reliable: false } )
    } catch (e) {
        console.error( 'Failed to create data channel. ' +
                       'You need Chrome M25 or later with RtpDataChannel enabled' )
    }

    function gotLocalDescription( desc ) {
        connections[uid].setLocalDescription( desc )
        server.send( desc, uid, server.room() )
    }

    connections[uid].createOffer( gotLocalDescription )
}
```

PeerConnection creates an response

```
function onoffer( offer, uid ) {
    connections[uid] = new webkitRTCPeerConnection( servers,
                                                    { optional: [{ RtpDataChannels: true }] } )

    function gotRemoteDescription( desc ) {
        connections[uid].setRemoteDescription( desc )
        server.send( desc, uid, server.room() )
    }

    connections[uid].createAnswer( gotRemoteDescription )

    function gotReceiveChannel( event ) {
        channels[uid] = event.channel
    }

    connections[uid].ondatachannel = gotReceiveChannel
}
```

ICE candidates are received as messages from the SimpleSignaling server.

```
server.onmessage = function( msg, uid, room ) {
    if( msg.type == 'offer' ) {
        onoffer( msg, uid )
    } else if( msg.candidate ) {
        try {
            connections[uid].addIceCandidate( msg )
        } catch( e ) {
            console.error( 'connections[uid].addIceCandidate', e )
        }
    } else {
        console.warn( 'server.onmessage: Unknown message type', msg )
    }
}
```

The `onawaken` `onicecandidate` handler seems to be performing correctly. When two tabs are opened the second will receive JSON candidate objects. When I pass those to `connections[uid].addIceCandidate`, I get the error `TypeMismatchError: DOM Exception 17.

The [code](https://github.com/wholcomb/SimpleSignaling/blob/gh-pages/examples/wall.js) and a [demo](http://wholcomb.github.io/SimpleSignaling/) are online.

---

What is passed to `addIceCandidate` needs to be a `RTCIceCandidate`. The final code looks like:

```
server.onmessage = function( msg, uid, room ) {
      var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate( msg )
      connections[uid].addIceCandidate( candidate )
}
```

Now I get `SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12`. In theory this is because I'm [calling `addIceCandidate` before `setRemoteDescription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396071/errors-when-ice-candidates-are-received-before-answer-is-sent). I have `setRemoteDescription` in `createAnswer`, but the callback is never getting executed.

---

To `onoffer` I added:

```
connections[uid].setRemoteDescription( new RTCSessionDescription( offer ) )
```

That cleared up the syntax errors. ICE messages are now getting sent successfully, but `connections[uid].ondatachannel` is never getting called.

Answer (score 1):

I added a handler for the result of `createAnswer`. The program now works.

```
server.onmessage = function( msg, uid, room ) {
    if( msg.type == 'answer' ) {
        connections[uid].setRemoteDescription( new RTCSessionDescription( msg ) )
    }
}
```

The working code is a wall application that connects any users with the page open. It is running at [wholcomb.github.io/SimpleSignaling/](http://wholcomb.github.io/SimpleSignaling/).