# WebRTC The ICE candidate could not be added

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am trying to establish a p2p audio/video connection b/w two peers. Following: [Getting started with WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/).

It works fine at my home in LAN Environment between 2 PCs, but throws an error message when running 
at my company's LAN Environment, there is part the javascript

```
function processSignalingMessage(message) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(message);

        if (msg.type === 'offer') {
            // Callee creates PeerConnection
            if (!initiator && !started)
                maybeStart();

            // We only know JSEP version after createPeerConnection().
            if (isRTCPeerConnection)
                pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg));
            else
                pc.setRemoteDescription(pc.SDP_OFFER,
                        new SessionDescription(msg.sdp));

            doAnswer();
        } else if (msg.type === 'answer' && started) {
            pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg));
        } else if (msg.type === 'candidate' && started) {
            var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
                sdpMLineIndex : msg.label,
                candidate : msg.candidate
            });
            pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
        } else if (msg.type === 'bye' && started) {
            onRemoteHangup();
        }
    }
```

when the first user recieved message "type":"candidate",get wrong

and part of the console log:

- Creating PeerConnection
- Created webkitRTCPeerConnnection with config "{"iceServers":[{"url":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]}"
- Adding local stream
- Sending answer to peer
- recieved message : {"type":"candidate","label":0,"id":"audio","candidate":"a=candidate:1613033416 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.1.233 56946 typ host generation 0\r\n"}
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The ICE candidate could not be added
- recieved message : {"type":"candidat".......}
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The ICE candidate could not be added
- recieved message : {"type":"candidat".......}
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The ICE candidate could not be added

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create the ICE candidate message by using just the msg.candidate,

```
var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(msg.candidate);
```

And pass that into the `addIceCandidate` function

Comment: I have solved the problem.[Errors when ICE Candidates are received before answer is sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396071/errors-when-ice-candidates-are-received-before-answer-is-sent) RemoteDescription should be set (which should be done at the moment of receiving offer). In my code I waited with setting remoteDescription and sending answer until browser gets the local stream.

Comment: Could you add the answer?

Comment: @yangJoe please remember to write an answer if you solved your own problem, so you can mark that as the accepted solution to this problem.