# addIceCandidate does not work well in Web RTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I've touched to Web RTC and I have to make the video chat application on web base.
When I add Ice candidate, I got this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The ICE candidate could not be added.
```

I tried to find out it and someone tell me that there's [errors when ICE Candidates are received before answer is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355913/webrtc-the-ice-candidate-could-not-be-added) but dont give any solution.
Could anyone please help me to solve it.
Thank you so much!

Here is my code:

...

```
serverConnection.onmessage = gotMessageFromServer;
```

...

```
function gotMessageFromServer(message) {
if(!peerConnection) { 
        start(false);
    }

var signal = JSON.parse(message.data);
if(signal.ice) {
    peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.ice));
} else if(signal.sdp) {
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp), function() {
        peerConnection.createAnswer(gotDescription, createAnswerError);
    });
}
```

}

Comment: That code seems wrong. For `signal.ice` you should be calling `addIceCandidate`, not `createOffer`. See [example in the spec](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#simple-peer-to-peer-example). You're also not showing the code that calls `addIceCandidate`, so it is hard answer.

Comment: Sorry, something wrong and I copy code with mistake. I edited it, addIceCandidate and I got that above error. :)